# SSD Disk that recommands Win7 instead of XP : what is the deal?

Tags: ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do SSD disks do not last as long with Windows XP as with other OS?](https://superuser.com/questions/404880/do-ssd-disks-do-not-last-as-long-with-windows-xp-as-with-other-os)

I've changed my hard drive to a SSD. The notice tells me that I should upgrade to Win7. What is the risk or trouble I cloud face if I don't? Is XP bad for SSD? Is Win7 better for SSD?

Comment: What notice exactly are you talking about?  There are specific features in `Windows 7` that makes it perform better on a SSD then `Windows XP` does on SSD.  `Windows XP` is no longer going to be supported in less then a year by Microsoft, its very likely, this notice is simply an attempt, to avoid people from installing an unsupoprted operating system on their computer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WinXP was not designed to take into count the different characteristics of the SSDs - notably that SSDs can wear out by having too many write cycles... Basically the difference is that Win7 is designed with that in mind, so it should use your SSD much more 'gently' regarding writes. HDDs didn't have this characteristic feature, and SSDs did not exist when XP was designed.

Also, same reason: WinXP doesn't support [TRIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIM)

Recommended reading: [SSD Write Amplification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_amplification)

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, Windows XP doesn't have a way to do TRIM support, which can really kill SSD performance

Comment: Maybe [the OS using the SSD wrong] is why there are reports of people who buy/install an SSD and then less than 1 year later the SSD dies?

Comment: Here is a link to [a blog post that describes many SSD harddrives failing in less than a year](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/05/02/) --> please note the AVERAGE failure time is 228 days!!! How is that acceptable?

Comment: Average failure rate in like 10 drives? Whoa, that's a weak statistics even in the US... However, the message of the article you just linked tells you: do frequent backups, and enjoy the power. I've yet to see the first failed SSD in my experience, whereas I've had a big heap of HDDs fail on me...

Answer (score 0):

I know there has already been an accepted answer but several automatic life extending processes  present on win 7 that are not on XP.

TRIM for one.

Automaticly Truning off defrag, ready boost, write cashing, prefetching, indexing and probably several other SSD life changing/extending/shortening options.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP does not recognize SSDs as anything than ordinary hard disks.  It does not support TRIM and does not attempt to optimize its operation for an SSD.

While the system will operate without obvious problems, on Windows XP, the maximum performance of the SSD cannot be realized and the lifespan of the SSD may be shorter than if used on a Windows 7 or newer system.

Answer (score -1):

Logically, if your computer can run Win7, then Win7 will be better than WinXP.
Maybe your SSD's installed driver is made for Windows 7.Try to find the same driver for WinXP.